# Email Image not Showing (Gmail)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image, email, gmail

I've composed an email in HTML that has an image in it.

The image "src" attribute has a URL pointing to a controller action endpoint on my server (ASP.Net) which returns a FileContentResult.

An example of the img tag looks like this:

```
<img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/controller/action?argument=value" width="600" height="300" alt="HeadingImage" title="HeadingImage">
```

The email displays as expected in Outlook.

If I take the source from Outlook and just view it in Chrome desktop, it still works fine.

If I visit the img URL in Chrome the image is downloaded.

However, if I view the email in Gmail the image does not display. Why might this be the case?
I get a single error in the console looking something like this:

```
ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/<SNIP>https://www.mywebsite.com/controller/action?argument=value GET https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/<SNIP> 404 ()
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Checking the log files generated by IIS at:C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 I can see no errors, just the endpoint being hit as expected I think.

Comment: No, Okay what you mean by `viewing in gmail`? `Gmail.com` in the browser? If so, is the browser console showing any errors when you view it?

Comment: Right, when viewing the email in Gmail & Chrome, there is a single 404 error for the image.... ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/<SNIP>https://www.mywebsite.com/controller/action?argument=value GET https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/<SNIP> 404 ()

Comment: Maybe GMail doesnt allow this kinda image embed? with controller to generate dynamic image?

Comment: I think you need to set Content Type of response in action if you not do so

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this it's work for me

Including the scheme in the src url (using "//" does not work - use full scheme EG: "https://")
    Including width and height attributes
    Including style="display:block" attribute
    Including both alt and title attributes

Comment: Thanks but I was originally missing the protocol from my example... it still does not work with the protocol. I tried your other suggestion of adding an inline style with display set to "block" but still no success. Also, I had already specified width, height, alt and title attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `http://` in image `src`

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/action?argument=value" width="600" height="300" alt="HeadingImage" title="HeadingImage">
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was missing this from the example... it still does not work with the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to add that image on your deployed project folder and then you need to specify the path of your Image :

```css
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/Images/YourImage.png" />
```

Cheers !!

Comment: Thanks, but I need the image to be generated on the fly based on an argument. That's why it is currently pointing to a controller action.